# ImportError: No module named typedefs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a standalone program using pyinstaller. In this process I am encountering the following error message:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "/home/russellb/pyFiles/dist/build/tt/out00-PYZ.pyz/sklearn.neighbors", line 6, in <module>
File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
File "dist_metrics.pxd", line 48, in init sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree (sklearn/neighbors/ball_tree.c:34295)
File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
File "dist_metrics.pyx", line 52, in init sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics (sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.c:25494)
  ImportError: No module named typedefs`
```

Any suggestions?

As a follow-up:

I've managed to import typedef and got rid of the above problem. Now I am encountering the following error message at the run-time.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 270, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "/home/russellb/pyFiles/dist/build/tt/out00-PYZ.pyz/sklearn.linear_model", line 21, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyi_importers.py", line 409, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, self._c_ext_tuple)
  File "weight_vector.pxd", line 10, in init sklearn.linear_model.sgd_fast (sklearn/linear_model/sgd_fast.c:9464)
ImportError: No module named weight_vector`

However, I could not find any module named weight_vector in the sklearn directory hierarchy in that specified location.

Any insights and suggestions?

Many thanks,

Comment: Your traceback is unreadable, is there a reason why you rolled back the edit?

Comment: earnestly, I do not know how to edit it so that it would be readable. Apologies

Comment: This error was generated when I tried to run the generated executable. pyinstaller generates the executable without any issues, except few warning such as
rebuilding out00-PKG.toc becuase it was missing

Comment: Is this the entire traceback?  Looks like it might be missing the last line

Comment: @zehnpaard: It is now the entire traceback. The last line was the one that was missing. Thank you :)

Comment: @Zulu: Thank you for your kind efforts. I hope it is code-snippet and not code-sample. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23250360/3155195) and the [PyInstaller docs](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#listing-hidden-imports)

Comment: Thank you @zehnpaad. Let me give a try and post back the results.

Comment: @zehnpaard: Thank you, the link has the clue for this problem and the problem solved

Answer (score 3):

You can add --hidden-import=modulename to your pyinstaller script. It will import this module and bind.

Comment: This helped! SkLearn caused 3 missing modules tor my Keras-based app. Providing them all explicitly solved the problem: pyinstaller -y --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree --hidden-import sklearn.tree._utils  "<myapp.py>"

Answer (score 2):

I used the tool auto-py-to-exe. It is a gui tool which calls the pyinstaller internally.
In the advanced options I've added to --hidden-import all the missing modules.
In the command line I saw all the modules as the parameters:

```
--hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.typedefs --hidden-import sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree --hidden-import sklearn.tree._utils
```

[image]