# Packing python scripts into .exe file while keeping imported modules

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have a python script I want to pack into `.exe` file for the ease of use. The python script makes extensive use of Tkinter module for nice GUI. I've packed it first into `.exe` using pyinstaller and the guide outlied here - https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

I have two problems. First is that my script makes use of FlowCal module, which doesn't come with Python's pyinstaller (I've made script using Spyder, and I'm using Python 3.8. to compile using pyinstaller) - so I installed FlowCal with `pip install FlowCal` so Python gets it too (I think that's how it works? Not too sure). But then FlowCal is dependent on various sklearn modules, and it would be a headache to install modules, compile to exe, then check if it works over and over. Is there a way that ALL modules script uses (and ALL modules that imported modules use) are compiled into the script?

Second problem is that alongside GUI I get another window. Picture included. How do I remove that window?

[image: Picture of that another window (right) with the GUI window (left)]

Comment: Pyinstaller should trace all modules and dependencies automatically. I usually install a minimal set of dependencies into a fresh Anaconda environment to have the smallest possible build size. For some modules, you might need to add explicit imports. A good start is here: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

Comment: There is nice wrapper around PyInstaller, [here is the link](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), called auto-py-to-exe. It is graphical interface that shows all PyInstaller options that can be configured when packing EXE. To remove black console window that you see you have to set in graphical interface option to make Windowed application, not Console. Also you have to check first that your application runs well without EXE, so that all modules are already pip-installed. Afterwards when building EXE pyinstaller will include all imported modules automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005004/importerror-no-module-named-typedefs
this might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another thing you can do without any hassle is using auto-py-to-exe. This will generate .exe from .py with writing command, just clicking some buttons in a GUI. For this, you have to give the command: `pip install auto-py-to-exe` in command prompt or PowerShell, whatever you like most. After successfully installing auto-py-to-exe, give the command `auto-py-to-exe` in your command prompt. Then give the necessary informations, and get your generated executable file!

Comment: The solution was using auto-py-to-exe with explicit addition of hidden modules. Hidden modules were sklearn.neighbors._typedefs,sklearn.utils._weight_vector, and  sklearn.neighbors._quad_tree.

Answer (score 1):

Add the missing modules to the hiddenimports

```
hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors.typedefs','sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree','sklearn.tree._utils']
```

Or use it when you create the exe in cmd as

```
--hidden-import=modulename
```