Error while converting my .py file to .exe file with pyinstaller
I'm trying to convert my .py file to .exe file with PyInstaller.
The .py file, which worked perfectly on Jupyter lab, is not working perfectly in the exe file.
This part of the code is causing the problem.
GEMINI API
        GOOGLE_API_KEY = next(api_keys_cycle)
        generation_config = {"temperature": 0.4,"top_p": 1,"top_k": 1,"max_output_tokens": 1000,}
        model_name = 'gemini-pro'
        prompt =f"""Name three famous basketball players.""" 
        wat = call_api(GOOGLE_API_KEY, prompt, model_name, generation_config)
        print(wat)

This worked perfectly on Jupyter, but is generating:

AttributeError: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'GenerativeModel'

What is generating this problem?
I upgraded PyInstaller and the Python version of the environment that I generated the exe file.
Nothing worked.

maybe it is related to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65918647/packing-python-scripts-into-exe-file-while-keeping-imported-modules

I dont think thats the code causing the issue as i am not seeing this in the code "AttributeError: module 'google.generativeai' has no attribute 'GenerativeModel'"

I agree with @LindaLawton-DaImTo. Can you show us the code where google.generativeai is used? And what's the current version of your PyInstaller and Python?

it was a problem with the python version. Solved the problem. Thanks
