# Pyinstaller OSError: Cannot load AutoItX

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, autoit

I used `import autoit`. The script is running perfectly from VSCode and from Control Panel. But when making it an executable with PyInstaller, when I run the .exe file I get this error message:

[image]

`pyinstaller --hidden-import=autoit --onefile run.py` didn't work. How to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Copy file(**AutoItX3_x64.dll**) from address

```
C:\Users\alire\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\autoit\lib\
```

2. Build folder(**autoit\lib**) in project and copy file there

Answer (score 0):

After some time of searching i find a solution about my problem.

The solution i found working was by using the `cmd`.

**1)** I use this command to define the **PATH** of the file:

`cd C:\Users\bilakos\Desktop\PYTHON_PROJECTS\BOT`

**2)** Then i use this command to create the working executable **.exe** file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data C:\Users\bilakos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\autoit\lib\AutoItX3_x64.dll;autoit\lib Bot.py
```

For me that worked. I hope if somebody experienced the same issue, to get help be reading my solution.